# Изменить цвет текста старого меню

Tags: android, android-menu

Материальный дизайн. Используется com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1.

<s>Как сделать, чтобы цвет `overflow` кнопки и цвет меню, вызываемой по хардварной кнопке на старых девайсах отличался. За их цвет отвечает атрибут : `android:textColorSecondary`. К сожалению , изменения цвета `overflow` тянет за собой изменение цвета меню, мне это не нужно 
Нужно изменить или `overflow` или цвет меню, но только по отдельности. Есть решение ? .</s>

Изначально , вопрос был ошибочно сформулирован. `android:textColorSecondary` - отвечает только за `overflow`. За цвет текста `options menu (старого)` отвечает атрибут `android:textColorPrimary` или `android:textColor` .

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9733538/3212712). Пишут, что можно переопределить стиль **overflow**. Возможно, поигравшись с атрибутами там, можно решить вашу проблему, т.к. если менять цвет в стиле для **overflow**, то стиль старого меню поменяться не должен будет.